# Пример удаления всех вхождений символа из строки

Tags: строки, c++

Добрый день.
У меня несколько вопросов по  примеру из самоучителя по Vizual C+.

1.Если на консоль вывести s[j], то выводится значение (а) , но ведь в условии 
сказано : если s[i] не равен 'a'.

2.Какую роль играет выражение - s[j] = '0';? если  это выражение закомментировать, то 
удаляемый символ 'а' опять появляется

```
#include <iostream>
#![alt text][1]include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[] = "travkaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";  //исходная строка 
    char c = 'a'; //удаляемый символ
    cout << s << endl;//вывод строки

    //Удаление из строки s всех вхождений символа 'а'
    int i = 0;//индекс для исходной строки
    int j = i;//индекс для модифицированной строки

    //цикл модификации исходной строки
    while (s[i])//пока в строке не нулевой байт
    {
        //проверить текущий символ строки
        if(s[i] != c) //если s[i] не равен 'a'

        //переписать текущий символ строки по новому индексу j
        // и  увеличить индекс j единицу
            s[j++] =  s[i];
        // и увеличить индекс i на единицу
            i++;
    }
     //запись нулевого байта в конец модифицированной строки
    s[j] = '\0';

    //вывод результата

    cout<< s << endl;

    getch(); 
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если на консоль вывести s[j], то
> выводится значение (а) , но ведь в
> условии сказано : если s[i] не равен
> 'a'

Смотря где выводите - до обрезания или после обрезания символа содержащего 'a'

> Какую роль играет выражение - s[j] =
> '0';? если это выражение
> закомментировать, то удаляемый символ
> 'а' опять появляется

В С/С++ признаком конца строки является символ '0'. Устанавливая s[j] в ноль фактически строка обрезается

Comment: *`'\0'`, не `'0'`

Comment: В самом цикле if вывел выражение - cout<<s[j]; , и на консоль выводится 
raavkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk, почему символа  'к'  так много , и почему вывелись 
два символа  'a' хотя в условии сказано - если s[i] не равен 'a'

Comment: Я так и напечатал '\0',но почему то выводится '0'.

Comment: Слэш почему то не выводится.